# Why does Flyway's Validate ignore missing files?

Tags: flyway

I use Flyway's [migrate](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate.html) when I start my application to, well, migrate the database. As per default `validateOnMigrate` is enabled and [validate](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/validate.html) reports an error if a already applied file is changed.

So far so good, but it seems to ignore cases where an already applied file is missing.

Secondly, if the schema contains a migration that is newer than the latest available, migrate logs a warning but doesn't fail either, for example:

> Schema `xxx` has a version (1.1.1) that is newer than the latest
>   available migration (1.0.1) !

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? I would like to have options like `failIfMigrationIsMissing` and `failIfSchemaIsNewer`.

All of this would be useful to make sure nobody installs or starts an older version on top of a newer database, e.g. downgrades. Actually I thought this would be the default behaviour, or do I miss something here?

Comment: Please file an enhancement request in the issue tracker. Thx.

Comment: @AxelFontaine: I made it two: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/988 and https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/989

Answer (score 1):

Here's a scheme that works with flyway 4.0.3. You can check all the migrations if your versioning is more complex.

```
flyway.migrate();
MigrationInfoService migrationInfoService = flyway.info();
MigrationInfo[] applied = migrationInfoService.applied();
MigrationInfo last = applied[applied.length - 1];
if (MigrationState.FUTURE_SUCCESS.equals(last.getState())) {
    throw new Exception("Database downgrade detected.");
}
```